# Overlap two buttons Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter. I have created two raised buttons. Both are created as widgets which are then being called in the main Scaffold widget. I want them to overlap with each other. I am trying the stack widget but then one button goes missing. I have also tried padding and positioning but nothing works. I do not want to use toggle buttons as those are just placed next to each other and are not overlapped.

Code

```
Widget business(context, setState) {


 
      return
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 60,
                width: 60,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: button2 ? primaryColor : Colors.white)
                  ),

                  color: button1 ? primaryColor : Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      button1 = true;
                      button2 = false;
                    });

                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                      msg:
                      "Business",
                      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                      timeInSecForIosWeb: 4,
                      backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    );
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    MyFlutterApp.office,
                    color: button1 ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );

    }

    else {
      return Container();
    }
  

  Widget personal(context, setState) {


    
      return
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 60,
              width: 60,
              child: RaisedButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    side: BorderSide(color: button1 ? primaryColor : Colors.white)
                ),

                color: button2 ? primaryColor : Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    button1 = false;
                    button2 = true;
                  });

                  Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg:
                    "Personal",
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                    timeInSecForIosWeb: 4,
                    backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  );
                },
                child: Icon(
                  MyFlutterApp.personal,
                  color: button2 ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );

    }

    else {
      return Container();
    
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You can use only 1 boolean variable, and from there display one button or the other. The way that you've done it does not change what you see, as their value are not used to determine what button is displayed

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Flutter Oficial Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html), you can use the Stack widget to achieve this effect. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liEGSeD3Zt8&ab_channel=Flutter) is a quick tutorial about this widget.

Using [RaisedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html), always remember to remove the elevation from the upper buttons, to not cause a black overlay impression.

Here is a example:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => {},
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Text('First'),
    ),
    RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => {},
      color: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      child: Text('Second'),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5z8c.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

I have minimal reproduction code of stack in flutter which I can give you

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Icon(
      Icons.shopping_cart,
    ),
    
      Positioned(
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
            child: Text(
              _bookModel.conutCart.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 8.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: you can try https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned/Positioned.fill.html widget as well @ajay131

Comment: And your logic is wrong. there are two icons which must be in one stack then and then they are an overlay. Thanks